# Force override method python

Tags: python, overriding

I have this code in which I try to override a couple methods of `BitstampWSS` with my own functions:

```
from bitex.api.WSS import BitstampWSS
import time
class Bitstamp(BitstampWSS):
    def __init__(self):
        wss = BitstampWSS()
        wss.channels=['order_book_xrpusd']
        wss.start()
        time.sleep(5999)    

    def order_book_callback(self, pair, data):
        print (pair)

    def xrpusd_ob_callback(self, data):
        print (data)
```

I't trying to override `order_book_callback` method from [BitstampWSS](https://github.com/nlsdfnbch/bitex/blob/master/bitex/api/WSS/bitstamp.py#L14) but my functions get never called but the ones original from `BitstampWSS`.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: How are you calling the methods? If you're doing `wss.whatever_method` then it won't call your method but the one from `BitstampWSS` as `wss` is an instance of `BitstampWSS` not `Bitstamp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that's wrong is that you are creating an instance of the class that you are trying to subclass. That's legal, but it usually makes little sense.

The next thing is that the `__init__()` method sleeps for almost 100 minutes before returning. So, although the new instance has not yet been initialised (because `__init__()` has yet to return), a `BitstampWSS` instance (internal to your class instance) has been created, and it has been started. Hence any message that invokes the callback will invoke the callback of the `BitstampWSS` object, not the one in your class.

I think that this will implement what you hoped for:

```
from bitex.api.WSS import BitstampWSS

class Bitstamp(BitstampWSS):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    # calls BitstampWSS.__init__()
        self.channels = ['order_book_xrpusd']

    def order_book_callback(self, pair, data):
        print(pair)

    def xrpusd_ob_callback(self, data):
        print(data)

bitstamp = Bitstamp()
bitstamp.start()
```

Comment: Works. Thank you so much!